# Ocultando ( $hidden ) password laravel 7

Tags: laravel, password

Estou necessitando ocultar o password de ser visto ou etc tanto na balde quando de qual quer forma, pois listo os usuários em uma blade para administração, mesmo utilizando a Model com Hidden como abaixo consigo ler o password.

{{ $user->password }}

A grande questão e mantar esse formato com -> como {{ $user->name }} e não {{ $user['name'] }} na blade.

Agradeço de coração uma ajuda, grande abraço !

Model:

```
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Administrator;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public function list()
    {
        $users = User::all()->toArray();


        return view('Administrator.users', compact('users'));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar os dados com '->' você tem que transformar o array em objeto.

Veja o exemplo da transformação:

```
$array = ['nome' => 'João', 'email' => 'joao@email.com'];
echo $array['nome'];

$object = (object) $array;
echo $object->nome;
```